# Sorting a query by Listbox with multiselect?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2007

My task is create a query that is filtered by the results of a listbox with multiselect. I have a table, named contacts, which has a field named 'Sources'. This is the field that is displayed in my listview. I am sorting by the 'Sources' value

From here, I can multiselect the options, and hit a submit button. When I do so, I get a query but it seems to simply display all of the values.

Therefore, my question is, how can I create a query sorted by the Sources tab? I know that I need a onclick function, but I am very unfamiliar with VB. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the following to use your control names. You didn't mention where/how your query is created, but you can merge this code with yours...

```
Private Sub cmdBuildWhere_Click()
Dim varItem     As Variant
Dim strWhere    As String

If Me.lstHierarchy.ListIndex < 1 And Me.lstHierarchy.ItemsSelected.Count = 0 Then   ' No items selected
    MsgBox "You did not select any sources. ", vbOKOnly, "Select Sources"
    Exit Sub
End If

strWhere = "WHERE "

For Each varItem In Me.lstHierarchy.ItemsSelected
    strWhere = strWhere & "[Sources] = '" & Me.lstHierarchy.Column(0, varItem) & "' Or "
Next varItem

' remove final ' or ' and add Sort
strWhere = Trim(left(strWhere, Len(strWhere) - 4)) & " Order By Sources;"

Debug.Print strWhere

End Sub
```